# What does the word "Atten" mean?

Tags: etymology

What does the first part "Atten" of the word "Attentäter" mean?

Comment: There's no such stem like _Atten_. The stem is _Attentat_.

Comment: Siehe auch http://www.mythoselser.de/attentat-begriff.htm

Comment: Das Atten vom Attentat ist verwandt mit dem Him von der Himbeere.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Das Him von der Himbeere kommt von Hinta (weibl. Hirsch) ist also nicht verwandt mit dem Herrn Atten.

Comment: Interessant: Wenn das Wort *Him* alleine dasteht, lese ich immer *Hirn*. Wenn es aber in einem anderen Wort steckt (*Himbeere* oder *Himberg*, eine Marktgemeinde südlich von Wien) erfasst mein Him ganz mühelos was da wirklich steht.

Comment: @deamentiaemundi  Danke für die Herleitung des Him. Was jedoch macht dich so sicher, dass Herr Atten nicht eben doch mit dem Hirsch verwandt ist?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*»Atten«* bedeutet gar nichts, diesen Wortstamm gibt es im Deutschen nicht. Das Wort *»Attentat«* stammt vom lateinischen *»attentāre«* ab. Das ist eine Nebenform von

> attemptāre

Dieses lateinische Wort bedeutet: *antasten, versuchen, jmdm. beizukommen suchen*

Es ist zusammengesetzt aus:

> ad-

Das bedeutet: *zu, an, hin(zu), heran, herbei*

und

> temptāre

Das heißt: *betasten, berühren, angreifen*

<sub>*Quelle: [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Attentat)*</sub>

Comment: Das lateinische Wort heißt eher attentare/attemptare (ohne ä, diesen Buchstaben gibt es im Lateinischen nicht)

Comment: @Rha: Augen auf! Dort steht nicht ä (ein kleines A mit Umlaut-Punkten) sondern ā (ein kleines A mit einem »Makron« genannten Querstrich). Dieses Zeichen wird unter anderem dafür verwendet, um in lateinischen Wörtern zu kennzeichnen, dass ein Vokal nicht kurz, sondern lang auszusprechen ist.

Comment: Hoppla, falsch gelesen.

Comment: Ausgehend von En *at:tempt* und der Präferenz, Partikel, Morpheme und "Clitics" nicht zu betonen, würde ich mal vermuten, die Deutsche Aussprache verfälsche den Ausdruck und erwecke den Eindruck eines eigenen Wortstammes, von *-tat*, *täther* (vgl. Ru *тать*, "thief" < \*(s)teH, *stehlen*). Ich verstand als Kind übrigens zuerst *Affen-Tat*, wobei ich der Affe gewesen wäre.

Comment: Siehe daher auch Nynorsk *avig* "unkind" (WIMRE; Gothisch würde besser passen), Bokmal *fugr*, "idem", sowie landschaftlich Deutsch *anficken, ficken* "Probleme bereiten, fertig machen". Zumal *ein Attentat auf jemanden vorhaben* sehr salop verwendet wird. Sonst wäre das deutsche Äquivalent *Anschlag*; Vgl *schleichen*, *sly*?